# StreamWriter стирает файл

Tags: c#

Нужно создать метод, который будет заменять строку просто вписав начало этой строки. Оно это выполняет, но программа после замены, когда записывает данные в файл, просто стирает его. Вот мои попытки:

```cs
private void _ReplaceProperties(string needfor, string replacefor)
            {

                string text = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Mineserv\\Servers\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\server.properties");
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Mineserv\\Servers\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\server.properties"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while((line = sr.ReadLine())!= null)
                    {
                        if(line.Contains(needfor))
                        {
                            replaceline = line;
                        }
                    }

                }

                text = text.Replace(replaceline, replacefor);

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Mineserv\\Servers\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\server.properties"))
                {

                    sw.Write(text);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
```

Тоесть в файле есть строка `online-mode=true` и я должен прописать метод `_ReplaceProperties("online", "online-mode=false");`
Но файл после данного процесса становится пустым.

Comment: вычитывайте ВЕСЬ файл в память полностью, меняйте нужные строки и записывайте ВЕСЬ файл обратно. Большую часть операций со строками в файле можно производить только таким способом, исключение - замена строк с одинаковой длинной в байтах(!), и то по ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо, но можете ли вы подсказать как можно в тексте построчно проверять текст? (После считывания)

Comment: Ну например загрузить как массив строк - `ReadAllLines`. Если уже прочитали как одну строку - сплит по `\n` в массив строк. Можно даже читать построчно и формировать новый файл с нужными значениями, а в конце заменить старый файл новым. Вариантов много, зависит от того как у вас организовано чтение, объем данных для обработки и т.д. Вечером-ночером может напишу пример, сейчас пока занят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно непонятно, зачем вы дважды получаете информацию из одного и того же файла: с помощью `File.ReadAllText` и с помощью `StreamReader`.

Вообще, если я правильно понял, ваш код прекрасно заменяется этим:

```
private void ReplaceProperties(string needfor, string replacefor)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    string replaced = text.Replace(needfor, replacefor);
    File.WriteAllText(path, replaced);
}
```